# TextCell in InerfaceBuilder for NSTableView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, tableview

I am quite new to NSTableView but as I tried to get things straight, I took a look at InterfaceBuilder!!
[TableView hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SWwf.png)
I understand that objects are responsible for scrolling and clipping. TableView is the real NSTableView instance. The object titled function list ist the NSTableColumn below that is my TableCellView objects. What I don't understand is the object TextCell. It doesn't seem anything to do. Even wrong colors and alike have no effect at all. I am using a view based variant. Is the TextCell solely for cell based TableViews?

I found that part not quite well documented. I am planning on building custom views for my table. So I was thinking a thorough understanding would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's strange that that's still there. It's useless and has no effect on anything, but you can't delete it. Ignore it.